What does Ombudsman Act, RSO 1990, s. 24(1) mean by “acted in bad faith”?
I can’t find any law or case that defines “acted in bad faith” in Ombudsman Act, RSO 1990, s. 24(1) -

24 (1) No proceedings lie against the Ombudsman, or against any person holding any office or appointment under the Ombudsman, for anything he or she may do or report or say in the course of the exercise or intended exercise of his or her functions under this Act, unless it is shown that he or she acted in bad faith [emphasis mine].

Hamalengwa v. Bentley, 2011 ONSC 4145 (CanLII), [21] didn't define "acted in bad faith".

[21]    Any claim against the Ombudsman is blocked by statute, unless it can be shown that he acted in bad faith. The plaintiff alleges malice, misrepresentation and fraud against the Ombudsman but, as discussed previously, particulars allowing an inference of bad faith are absent from the statement of claim.

ElZayat v. Ontario (Ombudsman), 2021 ONCA 336 (CanLII), [4] didn't define "acted in bad faith".

[4]         The motion judge found that there was no genuine issue for trial: the respondent was immune from proceedings unless it could be shown that it acted in bad faith and there was no evidence of bad faith before the court. The appellant put forward no evidence on the motion.

Mazhero v. Yukon (Ombudsman), 2001 YKSC 520 (CanLII) did not define “acted in bad faith”, but did Justice Marceau hint that delay and bias constitute “bad faith”?

[20]         There is no delay in processing the petitioner’s complaints which could be considered inordinate and therefore no reason to even consider delay as evidence of bias.


[26]         I am mindful of the general law in this area which states that actual bias need not be shown, rather the test is whether there is an apprehension of bias.


The leading Canadian law definition is as follows:

Good faith and its opposite, bad faith, imports a subjective state of
mind, the former motivated by honesty of purpose and the latter by
ill-will.

From here.

Bad faith is like obscenity - you know it when you see it
In the context of the duties of an ombudsman, it would be bad faith if there had not been an honest, dispassionate, and impartial attempt to discharge those duties.
Obviously, an ombudsman who acted corruptly would be acting in bad faith, but bad faith does not necessarily have to rise to the level of criminality. Other things that might be bad faith include deliberately or recklessly:

Acting with obvious bias
Acting prejudicially
Failing to afford procedural fairness
Acting dishonestly
Failing to engage with the material before them

However, an ombudsman who was merely careless or negligent would not be acting in bad faith - bad faith requires more than just being bad at your job.
A person who wanted to prove bad faith would need strong and compelling evidence that the ombudsman was deliberately and knowingly ignoring their responsibilities.
